# Can the roots of this equation be obtained?

Tags: calculus, roots

I have the following equation:

$$x \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} + C1\right]^2 - C2 = 0$$

I need to find the roots for $x$ and I'm finding it to be rather difficult. Wolfram throws [6 roots in a format I don't understand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%20*%20%281.%20%2F%20sqrt%281%20%2B%20x**2%29%20%2B%20C1%29**2%20-%20C2%3D0%2C%20x):

[image]

Is there any somewhat simple (or at least not extremely complicated) way to present these roots?

Comment: I remember running into this syntax once when doing some special function integration. Bad memories.

Comment: @CameronWilliams well that's not good for me then...

Comment: ToRadicals[] would be the command in Mathematica, but it only works up to degree 7 polynomials or so and it is not any simpler. # is the same as x in the Root object.

Comment: Well, WA just squared $(\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}})^2=(\frac{C_2}x-C_1)^2$ and developped it to the corresponding $6$ degree polynomial and says, your solutions are the six roots of this thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking at it quickly, it looks like the equation simplifies to a sixth-degree polynomial with essentially general coefficients (of course those coefficients depend only on $C_1$ and $C_2$, but they're still complicated). That means that solving likely reduces to solving an arbitrary sixth-degree polynomial, which is known to be impossible using elementary functions. That syntax from WolframAlpha looks like it's just saying "the roots are the first root of this polynomial, the second root of this polynomial, the third root of this polynomial...". If you choose particular values for $C_1$ and $C_2$, you can likely get WolframAlpha to give you approximate solutions; but it seems like there's no practical way to find an exact solution in general.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Reese.